# How to get the percentage change data of a candle in PineScript?

Tags: pine-script, percentage, trading, tradingview-api

is there some kind of inbuilt function in pine script that returns the percentage change of a candle or group of candles?
or just code it from scratch

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for bar to bar percent change. You can sub in numbers for the commented section for a group of bars.

```
per = (close-close[1]) / close[1] * 100    
// (end price - start price) / start price * 100
```

Comment: If a candle is 1 seconds, by using `close-close[86400]` can I get the 1 day percent change?

Comment: That would give you a rolling window equal to one day. The candle it references would be constantly moving, and if in a session based market the window may not be equal to one day anymore...

Comment: What do you mean by `if in a session based market the window may not be equal to one day anymore`?, would it be close to a day?  I am using alerts in 1 second interval (candle) and was looking for a way to find out 1 day percent change

Comment: I mean the stock market for example, so the number of 1 second candles in a day would differ between session times, after hours activity, or if there isn't a sale then no candle is printed... You could use the request.security() function to access HTF data...

Comment: I still did not get it. Shouldn't 1 second candle amount in a day be fix number as `86400`? And I believe there is always close value is printed even if price remains same.